# I'm getting the error: no suitable conversion function from std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>> to char exists

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the operator >> and I want to read each character from an input but i get that error.
Here is the code:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Natural_Big_Number number)
{
    int x;
    input >> x;
    number.set_nr_digits(x);
    char c;
    while ((c = input.get(c)))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `input.get(with_parameter)` returns an `istream`, but you're assigning it to a `char`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get .  You probably wanted the call to `.get()` <== no parameter

Comment: I get the same exact error with or without the parameter

Comment: check the link in my answer - it shows it working.  If you put the `c` back as a parameter, you get the error message you were getting before.

Comment: @AlinCatalinPreda In this case, the second parameter of `operator>>` should be a reference, or this will not do anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to not specify a parameter to `.get()` if you want it to return the character.   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

istream& operator>>(istream& input, int number)
{
    char c;
    while ((c = input.get()))
    {

    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/XSKvv4

If what you want is to check the boolean value of the stream for `false`ness, then you would do what was mentioned in the comments, instead:

```
while (input.get(c))
```

which stores the character in `c` then checks the `bool` value of the returned input stream.

Comment: That still won't work right. He just needs `while (input.get(c))`

Comment: @0x499602D2 addressed.